# I am having problems selecting button in selenium for java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, junit5

Hello I am trying to select and click on the button "Book Now" yet when I view the source code it shows the following...

```
<div class="pl-0 mr-3 sticky-btn-wrapper">
    <div class="ko-container book-now-btn-container">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary text-uppercase btn-landing go-to-session" data-eid="757231" data-aid="97739" data-isavailable="true"> Book now</button>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="btn-book-top sticky-btn-wrapper justify-content-end" id="book-button-top">
    <div id="sticky-bottom-btn" class="sticky-bottom-btn flex-row w-100">
        <div class="ko-container book-now-btn-container">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary text-uppercase btn-landing go-to-session" data-eid="757231" data-aid="97739" data-isavailable="true">Book now</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I inspect the "Book Now" link in Firefox is shows the following

```
<div class="ko-container book-now-btn-container">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary text-uppercase btn-landing go-to-session" data-eid="757231" data-aid="97739" data-isavailable="true">
                Book now
            </button>
</div>
```

[Why are there two instances of button class="btn btn-secondary text-uppercase btn-landing go-to-session" ??]

I have tried to select the first instance with

```
WebElement wb = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath ("//div[@class='pl-0 mr-3 sticky-btn-wrapper'] and button[@class='btn btn-secondary text-uppercase btn-landing go-to-session']"));
wb.click();
```

But I get the following exception in Junit...

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 
Given xpath expression "//div[@class='pl-0 mr-3 sticky-btn-wrapper'] and button[@class='btn btn-secondary text-uppercase btn-landing go-to-session']" 
is invalid: TypeError: Document.evaluate: Result type mismatch
```

Any help would be Sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `and` operand for locator, just change xpath to:

`//div[@class='pl-0 mr-3 sticky-btn-wrapper']//button`

Keyword `and` you need to use in the case when you have two or more similar elements and you need to add some more restrictions. Also `and` argument should be applied to the same tag, not for different.

For example:

```html
<div class='1' style='1'>
    <button>Button1</button>
</div>

<div class='1' style='2'>
    <button>Button2</button>
</div>

<div class='2' style='2'>
    <button>Button3</button>
</div>
```

If you need to get locator to the Button2:

`//div[@class='1' and @style='2']/button`

Comment: Thank you for this, this is the code that I wound up using ...       
     
      //this books the event by clicking the "Book Now" event
      String BookNowEventXpath ="//a[ contains( text(), 'Book now') ]";
      By BookNowEventSelector =By.xpath(BookNowEventXpath);
      WebElement BookNowEvent= myDriver.findElement(BookNowEventSelector);
      BookNowEvent.click();

Answer (score 0):

Please try below xpath :

```
//div[contains(text(),'Book now')]
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If there are multiple entry, Please try indexing :

```
(//div[contains(text(),'Book now')])[1]
```

or

```
(//div[contains(text(),'Book now')])[2]
```

in fact, you can have `[3]`, `[4]` and any number, But you will have to make sure that in HTML DOM it is 1/1 matching.